# Is there a way to allow multiple instances of an application on macOS?

Tags: process, finder, macos-sierra

Is there a way to allow multiple instances of an application on macOS?

My app requires the main process and a helper process. On launch, it uses NSTask to launch another copy of itself with a command line parameter to become the helper process.

If the main App crashes, and the helper app is still running, it's impossible for the user to launch the main app again because macOS only allows one instance to run at a time.

Is there any way around this? Either to allow multiple instances in general or to make Finder think the helper process isn't the same as the original process?

Comment: On macOS, a helper process is usually a separate executable/bundle inside your app bundle (which eliminates this issue). Could you provide more details on why you need a helper process? What are you doing in the helper app that you can't or don't want to do in the main app (given they are the same app)? There may be a different architecture that better fits your needs.

Comment: The helper app provides some virtual midi ports. I use a helper process since I want the midi ports available even when the main app isn't running. Otherwise my app and the apps on the other end of the midi ports would need to be launched in a specific order.

Comment: I suggest that you extract this code out to a separate helper app inside your main app bundle (which will resolve your current issue). That would be the standard way of structuring this - the helper app is a separate app with a separate bundle ID, which is started by your main app.